# Create multiple items from an array

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first attempt at using App Script, but I want to create a form with 50 questions with the same two choices utilizing radio buttons.

I was hoping I could create an array with the questions and just iterate through each question in the array (with a `for` loop) to create the question items with the same choices, but not exactly clear on how to implement this perhaps via an index with the `.setTitle(item)` object.

Thank you and any guidance would be appreciated.

```
// radiobuttons  
var items = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"];         
var arrayLength = items.length; 
var roundNumber = 0;
var choices = ["Successful", "Unsuccessful"];  

for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++ { . // Incomplete

form.addMultipleChoiceItem()  
   .setTitle(item)  
   .setChoiceValues(choices)  
   .setRequired(true);
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is missing the closing `)`

Comment: But, wouldn't I need an index or something to refer to each array element within the .setTitle(item) like .setTitle(i) versus .setTitle(item) ?

Comment: Yes you would. I see now, you want to loop through items?

Comment: Side notes, there's no point in using `arrayLength`, just do the standard way, `i < items.Length`. And woudn't a better name for `items` be `titles`, seeing as that's what you're using it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is loop through `items`, there's 3 ways to do so:

**For Loop**

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
   form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle(items[i])           // Index the array by using items[i]
      .setChoiceValues(choices)
      .setRequired(true);
}
```

**Foreach Loop**

```
foreach (var item in items) {
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
       .setTitle(item)
       .setChoiceValues(choices)
       .setRequired(true);
}
```

**Anonymous Function**

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
    form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
       .setTitle(item)
       .setChoiceValues(choices)
       .setRequired(true);
}
```

They all do the same thing, but different syntax.